# Sun Grid Engine: name output file using value stored in variable

Tags: bash, sungridengine

Thanks in advance for the help.

I am trying to pass a job using

```
qsub -q myQ myJob.sh
```

in myJob.sh I have

```
# Name of the output log file:
temp=$( date +"%s")
out="myPath"
out=$out$temp
#$ -v out
#$ -o $out
unset temp
unset out
```

What I want is for my output file to have standard name with the unix timestamp appended to the end such as myOutputFile123456789

When I run this, my output file is named literally "$out" rather than myOutputFile123456789.  Is it possible to do what I want and if so how might I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't set -o or -e programtically inside the script.  What you can do is point them at /dev/null then redirect inside the script.  Assuming you want the timestamp to be the time the job ran and the jobscript is a bourne shell script (including bash,ksh,zsh scripts) then the following should work

```
#$ -o /dev/null
exec >myPath$(date +"%s")
```

You'll be throwing away any output from the prolog/epilog though.